# How to get which button is clicked using 'useForm' from 'react-hook-form'

Tags: reactjs

How to get status value as "APPROVED" when 'APPROVE' button is clicked, and "DENIED" when 'DECLINE' is clicked. Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After searching,  i din't get any reference. So, I added onClick to both buttons and passing Approve,Declined values from that on click function to

```
 onClick={() => clickedOnSubmit('Approve')}
 onClick={() => clickedOnSubmit('Decline')}
 clickedOnSubmit = (type: any) => {setSubmitType(type) }.
```

here i'm setting the state value. on onSubmit i'm using that submitType. This is working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

```
onClick={() => form.setValue('name', 'value', { shouldValidate: true })}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).